# Turn off Alt+Right shortcut on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, rstudio

How do I turn off the `Alt`+`Right` shortcut on ubuntu 18.04 that brings me to a terminal window. I don't see it listed in the keyboard settings. I ask because it conflicts with an IDE I use called RStudio, which also uses that key binding for a different shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this is a confirmed bug in launchpad[1] due some recent updates. Until the fix you can run this command in console to prevent that behavior:

```
sudo kbd_mode -s
```

[1] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/520546